# Как лучше оформить такое предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, прямая-речь, цитирование

**Как сказал мой дядя, «Мы прорвемся».**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов оформления — множество (не забываем про точку в конце предложения).

С прямой речью:
**Сказал мой дядя: «Мы прорвемся».

Мой дядя сказал так: «Мы прорвемся».**

С цитированием (если по контексту есть такая необходимость):
**Как сказал мой дядя, «мы прорвемся».**
Следует обратить внимание на то, что цитата является частью предложения, поэтому писать ее следует со строчной буквы.
Из статей:
*Как сказал Одилон Редон, «ставить логику зримого на службу незримому».

Как сказал Борис Немцов, "Кремль решил независимое радио уничтожить".*

С косвенной речью:
**Как сказал мой дядя, мы прорвемся.**
Такое написание — самое простое и удобное. Слова "мы прорвемся" известны и общеупотребительны, используются часто, поэтому нет нужды их заключать в кавычки.

*Как сказала Джулия, зло нельзя увидеть, но его можно почувствовать* (Г. Гифьюн)
Мы должны идти, мы прорвемся, осталось недалеко, за лесом ― наши!.. [Юрий Бондарев. Берег (1975)]

Comment: Спасибо. Напишу со строчной и в кавычках после запятой)